# Big O for number of operations for a decreasing function

Tags: loops, complexity-theory, big-o

I have a problem with a loop that requires a decreasing number of operations each time the loop executes. Here's the code:

`for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
     ...code that takes at most 100/i operations to execute...
}`

I need to find a big O that describes the number of operations. I think what's tripping me up here is that bigger n = more operations, but the growth is smaller.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Harmonic number 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/n is O(log n)

Also, what if n > 100? For instance: Is 100/12345 operations well defined?

Comment: I assume that it would be rounded down to 0. I don't think it makes a difference, does it?

Comment: @xxpor: It does, as then we can do better and say it is O(1) :-). (Never more than 100(1 + 1/2 + ... + 1/100))